# Sort the values (Set -> SortedSet) of the Map with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, hashset, sortedset

How to sort values of the `Map<String, Set<String>>` i.e. convert to `Map<String, SortedSet<String>`> with streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over each entry and convert the `Set<T>` (e.g. `HashSet<T>`) to a `SortedSet<T>` (e.g. `TreeSet<T>`) as:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> input = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, SortedSet<String>> output = new HashMap<>();
input.forEach((k, v) -> output.put(k, new TreeSet<>(v)));
```

or with streams as:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> input = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, SortedSet<String>> output = input.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, a -> new TreeSet<>(a.getValue())));
```